# Designing a JButton using XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, look-and-feel, synth

I am trying to change the design of JButton using XML (Synth). I created the jbutton but it doesn't look like a normal button.

Here is an image of button.

[image]

```xml
<synth>
<style id="button">
    <opaque value="false"/>
   <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="1"/>
   <state>
      <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="///D:/JAVA SAN_KAR/XMLDesigns/src/images/button_default.png"
           sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" paintCenter="false" stretch="true"/>
      <insets top="10" left="10" bottom="10" right="10"/>
      <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#000000"/>
      <color type="TEXT_BACKGROUND" value="#c8ebff"/>
   </state>
</style>
<bind style="button" type="region" key="Button" />
</synth>
```

Comment: Now, What is your question?

Comment: sorry here is the code

Comment: you have provided a background for the button.... and that is why it is looking like that... I really don't understand what you mean by "normal button"

Comment: I mean I don't want the white portion in that button.

Comment: try to add this <color value="#6699EE" type="BACKGROUND"/> inside the state tag, also remove the <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#000000"/>

Comment: doesn't worked.....:(